# Как написать бота на discord.py, генерирующего заданное количество случайных чисел в определённом диапазоне?

Tags: python, discord, случайные-числа, discord.py

Чтобы эффект был как от от:

```
import random

x = int(input())

while x != 0:
   y = random.randint(1, 10)
   print(y)
   x-=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Инструкция1](https://habr.com/ru/post/511454/), [Инструкция2(на английском, но очень хорошая)](https://tutorial.vcokltfre.dev/tutorial/03-hello/)

```
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import time

bot = commands.Bot("!")


@bot.command()
async def get_random_num(ctx, num: int):
    if isinstance(num, int):
        for i in range(num):
            await ctx.send(random.randint(1, 10))
            time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы ввели не число!")


bot.run("your token")
```

Comment: Сугубо благодарен, но отмечу, что при попытке прописать в range() num, а не число скрипт выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Поправил. Теперь он будет отвечать в чат, если это не число